# Bootstrap 4 -- Moving links to the right of the navbar with a toggle button

Tags: html, css, bootstrap-4

I was attempting to move the links from the left of the navbar to the right side and it wouldn't let me. I've tried floating it to the right and nothing had happened, same with position:relative; right: 200px; and padding-right: -200px;. If anyone has any other suggestions it would be appreciated thank you.

```
<nav class="navbar navbar-toggleable-md navbar-light bg-faded">

    <button class="navbar-toggler navbar-toggler-right" type="button" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#navbarSupportedContent" aria-controls="navbarSupportedContent" aria-expanded="false" aria-label="Toggle navigation">

        <span class="navbar-toggler-icon"></span>

    </button>

    <a class="navbar-brand" href="index.html">

        <img id="logo" src="images/logo.png" width="200" class="d-inline-block align-top" alt="">

    </a>

    <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="navbarSupportedContent">

        <ul class="navbar-nav mr-auto">

            <li class="nav-item">
                <a class="nav-link active text-white" href="index.html">Home <span class="sr-only">(current)</span></a>
            </li>

            <li class="nav-item">
                <a class="nav-link text-white" href="services.html">Services</a>
            </li>

            <li class="nav-item">
                <a class="nav-link text-white" href="portfolio.html">Portfolio</a>
            </li>

            <li class="nav-item">
                <a class="nav-link text-white" href="about.html">About</a>
            </li>

        </ul>

    </div>
</nav>
```

Answer (score 32, accepted):

You're using the `.mr-auto` so you have `margin-right: auto !important` and the nav-items left aligned.
If you change the class to `.ml-auto` you have `margin-left: auto !important` and your nav-items are right aligned

Comment: Confirmed in jsfiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/sayLz41a/

Comment: Modified jsfiddle https://jsfiddle.net/sayLz41a/1/ (with black text on white navbar instead of white text on white navbar)

Comment: simplest, most illustrative answer I've ever seen. Thanks @DestinatioN

Comment: I have a similar request but where should I modify.... in Layout page?

Comment: @singhswat that depens on where your navbar is

Answer (score 1):

Modify some css in bootstrap:

Used `justify-content: end;` to start content for end

```
.mr-auto {
    margin-right: 0 !important;
}
.navbar-toggleable-md .navbar-collapse {         
    -webkit-justify-content: flex-end;
    justify-content: flex-end;  
}
```

Here is fiddle code: https://jsfiddle.net/0ewenvcb/2/

Comment: This doesnt appear to be working.. links are still on the left :(

Comment: in fiddle it's working..

Comment: http://imgur.com/nCwNwGi on Chrome OSX Version 55.0.2883.95 (64-bit) links are left aligned in the fiddle link in your answer (https://jsfiddle.net/0ewenvcb/1/)

Comment: Updated my code & fiddle

Answer (score 1):

After trying all options, the menu-icon (navbar-toggler-icon) was not moving to the right in Bootstrap 4.1.
I tried the following work around:
Under **`@media (max-width:575px)`** - added `.navbar-header {width:100%;}`, and under class **`.menu-icon`** (I named it menu-icon) `{justify-content:end;}`.
This moved both the `navbar-brand` and `menu-icon` to the right.  To move the `navbar-brand` to the left, in the HTML added class `mr-auto` to `navbar-brand`. This worked just fine for me.

Answer (score 0):

If all above fails, I added 100% width to the navbar class in CSS.  Until then mr-auto wasn't working for me on this project using Bootstrap 4.1.